# Emacs init file won't load at start up

Tags: windows, emacs, init

I'm trying to run Emacs v22.2 on a Windows 7 computer. However, the `init` file isn't loaded at start up (loading it manually with `M-x load-file` works fine).

I've tried using both:

```
~\.emacs, ~\_emacs 
~\.emacs.d.init.el
```

but the problem persists.

Evaluating `(insert (getenv "HOME"))` returns the expected value.

Comment: Is there anything in your *Messages* buffer? C-x b to switch to that buffer.

Comment: Have you tried ~/.emacs.d/init.el?

Comment: This is my _messages buffer_ after start up:   

`("C:\\home\\bin\\emacs\\bin\\emacs.exe")`
`Loading encoded-kb...done`
`load-with-code-conversion: Symbol's value as variable is void: setenv`

 `~/.emacs.d/init.el` doesn't work either.

Comment: 22.2 is really old. You may wish to upgrade to 23.3, or the latest pre-test version of 24 ( http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/ )

Answer (score 7):

Depending on how you open emacs in Windows 7, it will look in different places for the .emacs file. If call it from within a shell (in cygwin, Msys, etc) it will look in the $HOME (~) location, if you run it form the installation directory by clicking on the icon, it looks for this file in the %APPDATA% location ( usually C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Roaming ). This can lead you in a merry chase all over the place.  I found that it is best to determine where you want the file to be stored, and the create symbolic links ( using windows mklink utility ) to all other possible locations.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue(on windows 10). The problem was that Emacs was reading `~\.emacs` instead of `~\.emacs.d\init.el` on startup. Shifting the contents of `~\.emacs` to `~\.emacs.d\init.el` and deleting `~\.emacs` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed the patched version of [Emacs](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html) on Windows 7, specified the environment variable `HOME=c:\klang`, checked out my decade old configuration files from github and added

```
(and (= emacs-major-version 23) 
  (defun server-ensure-safe-dir (dir) "Noop" t))
```

to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and was up and running.

What you are missing is some component from `mule.el`, just install the new version of emacs to fix it.

If `HOME` is not set in the genereal environment, `(getenv "APPDATA")` will probably take over and emacs will try to read your init file somewhere under that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've just managed to solve the same problem (lcollado and klang's answer gave me a small hint on how to fix it).

I had set up a configuration file at `C:\Users\Edwin\.emacs.d\init.el` and when I tried to get Emacs to load it, it didn't. My initial thought was to make an `init.el` file at `C:\Users\Edwin\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d\init.el` which would load my original configuration file. However, I wanted a simpler solution.

Then I remembered that *Symbolic Links* exist. So I did a few searches on how to make a symbolic link in Windows and the difference between *Hard Links* and *Soft Links*.

My first attempt was to make a soft link that pointed to my `init.el`. But Emacs ignored the link and started without the `init.el`.

The next attempt that did work was a hard link. The steps that I did was as follows:

1. Open Command Prompt with Administrative Privileges.
   a. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
   b. Type "cmd.exe" and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   c. Tap "Yes" when Windows asks for Administrative Privileges.
2. Go to your home directory.
   a. Type `cd C:\Users\<your name>`.
3. Run the following command to make a hard link in `C:\Users\<your name>\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d\init.el`:

   ```
   :: mklink /h Destination Source
   :: Destination - Where do you want the hard link to be and what will be it's name?
   :: Source      - What file do you want to link?
   mklink /h AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d\init.el .emacs.d\init.el
   ```